# Redirect .htm to .php under same domain along with get value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My site hosted on linux. My four domains and some subdomains parked on root directory. Now I have changed all *.htm* files as *.php*. When I tried to redirect

with *.htaccess* by adding the matter `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [r=301,nc]` on it, it does not bring get values. I want to redirect all *.htm* to *.php* on same domain along with get value. I am tired to find matching code before posting this question. Kindly help me.

With thanks and regards,
Leelakh Ran.

Comment: Do you have other rules?

Comment: my query solved by following line on .htaccess file

RedirectMatch 301 (.*)\.htm$ $1.php

Answer (score 0):

What you forgot is the append query string flag `QSA` :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ $1.php [R=301,NC,QSA]
```